# is there way to createElement from a page called admin.htm to creat input text to an index.html both are in the same folder

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner in coding and JavaScript is my first program language so 
I am trying to figure things out here . My question:  is there way to `createElement` from a page called `admin.htm`  where I click a button and the button output shows" input type " text"  on `index.html`  both pages are in the same folder. I am trying to make a form control panel where it can generate input to a different page.

the index.html code is

```
    <body>
 <form id="formsc">   </form>     
<script src="admin.js"></script>
</body>
```

the admin.html code is :

```
<body>
<h1> Control Panel</h1>
<label for="btntext"> Creat text form by clicking sumbit:</label><br>
<input type="button" value="sumbit">
<script src="admin.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript cod is

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function formtext() {
let textInput = document.createElement("input");
let newButn = setAttribute("type", "text");
textInput.appendChild(newButn);
let position = document.getElementById("formsc")[0];
position.appendChild(textInput);});
formtext();
```

the code above didn't work with me and I  am not sure if the code is correct or not .

Comment: `let position = document.getElementById("formsc")[0];` has `[0]` at the end. That is not needed. More importantly, it's not possible the way you are doing it. One thing you could do is call `window.open('index.html')` from your admin page to open the index page and have a reference to it. That way you can manipulate the document in that window.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you:

```
//admin.html
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="sumbit">

//admin.js
var indexPage = window.open('index.html'); //opens new window for index page

function formtext() {
    let textInput = indexPage.document.createElement("input");
    textInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    textInput.value = "my input text";
    let position = indexPage.document.getElementById("formsc");
    position.appendChild(textInput);
}

document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", formtext);

formtext();
```

Comment: it didn't work it .  when i opened the admin page the " index.html" opened  immediately without I click the button  and the page was empty . There was no text field.

Comment: It opened immediately because of the last line: formtext();   You can remove that line.  And remove the admin.js link in your index.html page.

Comment: i have tried that , and it didn't create text field in index.html page.

Comment: Did you add `id="submitBtn"` to your submit button?

Comment: If you mean in the admin.html then yes.

Comment: When you click the submit button, does it call `formtext` function? Do you know what is not working?

Comment: When I clicked the button in the admin.html it opened the index. html page without a text filed .